# Mixed SKAnnotations customViews

Tags: android, skmaps

I'm having trouble re-adding SKAnnotations to my map. 
The map displays 2 SKAnnotations of 2 cities in India: New Delhi and Chandigarh (New Delhi's layout contains a white background while Chandigarh's just a new RelativeLayout with a TextView).
After a few rounds of deleting all SKAnnotations and then re-adding them, the customViews get mixed up. Here is what the map should look like:

[image: 2 Correct customView for each Annotation]

And here's what might happen after a few deletions and re-addings:
[image]

Code for adding the annotations:

```
public void addAnnotations() {
    SKAnnotation newDelhi = new SKAnnotation(444);
    newDelhi.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
    newDelhi.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
    SKAnnotationView newDelhiAnnotationView = new SKAnnotationView();
    RelativeLayout newDelhiCustomView =
            (RelativeLayout) ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                    R.layout.annotation_layout, null, false);
    newDelhiCustomView.setTag("new delhi");
    newDelhiAnnotationView.setView(newDelhiCustomView);
    newDelhi.setAnnotationView(newDelhiAnnotationView);
    TextView newDelhiTextView = (TextView) newDelhiAnnotationView.getView().findViewById(R.id.annotation_textview);
    newDelhiTextView.setText("New Delhi");
    SKCoordinate newDelhiLocation = new SKCoordinate(77.179163, 28.619828);
    newDelhi.setLocation(newDelhiLocation);

    SKAnnotation chandigarh = new SKAnnotation(555);
    chandigarh.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
    chandigarh.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
    SKAnnotationView chandigahrAnnotationView= new SKAnnotationView();
    RelativeLayout chandigarhCustomView =
            new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
    chandigarhCustomView.setTag("chandigarh");
    TextView chandigarhTextView = new TextView(getActivity());    
    chandigarhTextView.setText("Chandigarh");
    chandigarhCustomView.addView(chandigarhTextView);
    chandigahrAnnotationView.setView(chandigarhCustomView);
    chandigarh.setAnnotationView(chandigahrAnnotationView);
    SKCoordinate chandigarhLocation = new SKCoordinate(76.778867,30.736094);
    chandigarh.setLocation(chandigarhLocation);

    String nd = (String)newDelhiAnnotationView.getView().getTag();
    String ch = (String)chandigahrAnnotationView.getView().getTag();

    mapView.addAnnotation(newDelhi, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
    mapView.addAnnotation(chandigarh, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
}
```

deleting annotations by calling:
`mapView.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();`

I'm at a comlete loss after trying to deal with this issue for about a week, TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a problem in a previous version of the SDK (<= 2.5.0 I think) where the SDK did not properly manage the IDs of the annotations (and therefore at times deleting the wrong annotation).

In 2.5.1 this was fixed (shown in the [release notes](http://developer.skobbler.com/release-notes#v2_5_1)) by exposing the [uniqueID](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.1/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKAnnotation.html#setUniqueID(int)) property.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work, but I've also found that adding the mapView.updateAnnotation(hotspot) does the trick.